# R Plotly multiple dimensions on a bar chart

Tags: r, bar-chart, plotly, stacked-chart

I have to create a stacked bar chart in plotly with data something like below

```
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = c("NY", "NY", "NY", "SFO", "SFO", "SFO"),
  var2 =  c("LOW", "Medium", "High", "Low", "Medium", "High"),
  value = c(10, 15, 20, 15, 20, 15)
)
```

Basically x axis will have 2 bars for var1, filled with values for each var2. In ggplot you can use var2 as fill but I can't figure out how to do this in plotly.

Can someone help?

thanks,

Manoj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
# Split the data
df_list <- split(df, df$var2)
# plot the data and add the traces for var2
plot_ly(df_list$Low, x=~var1, y=~value, type="bar", name="Low") %>%
  add_trace(y= df_list$Medium$value , name = "Medium") %>%
  add_trace(y= df_list$High$value, name = "High") %>%
  layout(barmode = "stack")
```

[image]

```
# A faster way would be something like this:
# First order var2
df$var2 <- factor(df$var2,levels = c("Low", "Medium", "High"))
# Plot 
plot_ly(df, x= ~var11, y= ~value, color= ~var2, type="bar") %>% layout(barmode = "stack")
```

Latter solution displays the colors in the legend not correctly, which seems to be a bug in the plotly version `plotly_4.5.2`. Plotting more then two bars on the xaxis is working without any problems. Try this data with three `var1` groups:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  var1 = c("NY", "NY", "NY", "SFO", "SFO", "SFO","Test"),
  var2 =  c("Low", "Medium", "High", "Low", "Medium", "High","Low"),
  value = c(10, 15, 20, 15, 20, 15,30)
)
plot_ly(df2, x=~var1, y=~value, color=~var2, type="bar") %>% layout(barmode = "stack")

# Or use ggplot
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=var1, y=value, fill=var2)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme_bw()
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jimbou, with first option and with my real data I am somehow getting a combination of one bar and two line charts. Would you know what might be wrong? Also, if I use option 2, is there a way to specify custom color for each of the Var 2 category?

Comment: Forgot to mention that my real data I am not able to use '~' before my x and y values. I do not get a chart if I use tilde before my variables. I have checked the data types and it is same as the sample data above so not sure what is going on. thanks

Comment: Are you using the most actual version of plotly? Check it using `sessionInfo()`.